# Suppose $\sum_{i = 1} a_i \sum_{i = 1} b_i < \infty$. If $\sum_{i = 1} a_i = \infty$, what does it say about $(b_i)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, infinity

Let $(a_i), (b_i)$ be two non-negative sequence.

Suppose $\sum_{i = 1} a_i \sum_{i = 1} b_i < \infty$. If $\sum_{i = 1} a_i  = \infty$, what does it say about $(b_i)$?

Does it necessarily mean that $\sum_{i = 1} b_i = 0$?

Comment: It $\sum_i a_i=\infty,$ it is not possible for $\sum_i a_i\sum_i b_i<\infty,$ because the product is undefined. If you mean something else, then you’ll have to be specific. For instance  you might mean if $\lim_{N\to\infty }\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i=\infty,$ and $\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_1^N a_i\sum_1^N b_i<+\infty,$ then what can we say about $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_1^N b_i?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, this is what I meant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. If the sum of the $b_i$'s is positive, then its product with the sum of the $a_i$'s is also infinite, contradicting the assumption.